# How do I create a comprehension that sorts by the number of values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Currently, I am trying to learn more about how to utilize comprehensions. However, I am stuck with this problem I have right now.

The dictionary I have:

```
d =  {'Second': {('Carrie', 3), ('Diane', 3), ('Bob', 3)},
      'Third': {('Alan', 2), ('Diane', 5)},
      'Fourth': {('Carrie', 2), ('Alan', 5)},
      'First': {('Bob', 5), ('Carrie', 5), ('Alan', 1), ('Diane', 1)} }
```

I am trying to sort it by the number of values each key has so it would look like this when returned. If the key both have the same amount of values, it would be sorted alphabetically.

**Desired Output:**

```
['First', 'Second', 'Fourth', 'Third']
```

**What I have so far however, I am unsure how to sort by the len of the values :**

```
d = {'Second': {('Carrie', 3), ('Diane', 3), ('Bob', 3)}, 'Third': {('Alan', 2), ('Diane', 5)}, 'Fourth': {('Carrie', 2), ('Alan', 5)}, 'First': {('Bob', 5), ('Carrie', 5), ('Alan', 1), ('Diane', 1)} }

def sorting(d):
    return sorted([key for key, value in db.items(), key = lambda x: -len( )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: There is no need for a comprehension construct here, you are sorting *keys*, iterating over a dictionary iterates over it's keys already: `sorted(d, key=lambda k:(-len(d[k]), k))` suffices

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answers posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary mapping keys to their length, and then call `sorted` on that.

```
d2 = {k: len(d[k]) for k in d}
sorted(d2, key=d2.get, reverse=True)
# ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

Using a `lambda` would eliminate the need for a mapping, but would also mean the key is a `lambda` function, ... but here it is:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda k: (len(d[k]), k), reverse=True)
# ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

Here, the key callback returns a tuple `(len(d[k]), k)` ensuring that sorting is first done by the length, and then in alphabetical order.

---

As a silly one-liner, you can do this:

```
(lambda d: sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True))({k: len(d[k]) for k in d}) 
# ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

This is just a stand-in for assignment expressions, I'm waiting for python-3.8.

Comment: Do you need to create a mapping dict? `sorted(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]), reverse=True)`

Comment: @AChampion I did it just to avoid the lambda!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reverse` parameter in the `sorted` function:

```
results = [a for a, _ in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:len(x[-1]), reverse=True)]
```

Output:

```
['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a `lambda` that returns two values. The length of the value, and a list of negative `ord`'s of all the characters in the key to negate the `reverse = True` for alphabetical sorting.

```
print(sorted(d.keys(), key = lambda a: (len(d[a]), [-ord(c.lower()) for c in a]), reverse = True))
#['First', 'Second', 'Fourth', 'Third']
```